# GAS calling withSuccessHandler throws TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google apps script that opens a prompt through which you can upload files to an external server. The function in the script tag in the prompt calls my server side GAS function using the `google.script.run` function.

I tried adding a `withSuccessHandler` hook so that the prompt code knows if my server side GAS function finished successfuly. But what I get is a `TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0`.

Every part of the code works normaly if I dont include the `withSuccessHandler` hook. But when I do include it, no matter how I restructure the code I always get this error.

Here is the error that gets thrown

```
TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0
at ke (3342396747-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__sl.js:formatted:1756)
at ge (3342396747-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__sl.js:formatted:1763)
at 3342396747-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__sl.js:formatted:252
at 3342396747-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__sl.js:formatted:447
at Object.withSuccessHandler (3342396747-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__sl.js:formatted:1725)
at FileReader.fr.onload (userCodeAppPanel:21)
```

Here is the script that calls the server side GAS script and passes the file object to it. The `withSuccessHadndler` hook calls a `success` function that just logs an "ok" statement.

```
function getFile() {

 const f = document.getElementById('files');
 let promises = []

 for (const [i, file] of [...f.files].entries()) {

 let filePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  
  fr.onload = (e) => {
    const data = e.target.result.split(",");
    const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
    
    try {
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).saveFile(obj); 
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    resolve('ok')
  }
  
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
 })
  promises.push(filePromise)
}

 Promise.all(promises).then(fileName => console.log(fileName));
}

function success() {
 console.log('ok');
}
```

Here is the html part of the prompt

```
<body>
 <form>
  <div id="progress" ></div>
  <input type="file" name="upload" id="files" multiple>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="getFile()" >
  <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
 </form>
</body>
```

And here is the server side GAS script. The `buildUrl` and `insertLink` functions just do some formating work and they do not affect the error if I comment them out. I also tried returning right after the `saveFile` function is called so that none of the below code gets executed, but the error still persists.

```
function saveFile(obj) {

 var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType,obj.fileName);

 var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var selection = activeSheet.getSelection();
 var cell = selection.getCurrentCell();

 var y = cell.getRow();

 var tag = activeSheet.getRange(y, 1).getValue();

 var fileName = obj.fileName.toString().toLowerCase()
   .replace(/ /g, "-")
   .replace(/š/g, "s")
   .replace(/č/g, "c")
   .replace(/ž/g, "z");

 var url =  buildUrl(tag, fileName);

 try {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
   method: "POST",
   contentLength: fileBlob.getBytes().length,
   contentType: fileBlob.getContentType(),
   payload: fileBlob,
   headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getToken()
   }
  }); 
 } catch(err) {
  showAlert('error', err);
 }

 insertLink(fileName, tag);

 return 'ok'
}
```

Not also that using a Promise in the `getFile` script makes no difference, I tried removing it but the error is still thrown.

Comment: Log the values and types of the object you're sending to GAS

Comment: @RafaGuillermo The object I am sending consists of three properties which are all strings and is perfectly valid. Like I said above if I remove the withSuccessHandler hook the script works normaly.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data or a test sheet so I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I found what the problem was. My GAS script is full of functions that perform other tasks and in the midst of all of those functions was a withSuccessHandler function that I must have put there while I was learning GAS. I removed it and now it works fine. I found that out while making a test sheet for you with only the necessary functions and it was working fine. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Tanaike I was thinking that this problem might have something to do with the FileReader so I know you know a lot more about that than I do perhaps you can take a look at this question.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to read this section of the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values

It discusses the kinds of things that you can't send through google.script.run.  Like you can't send Date() objects.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have checked the documentation and it does not seem I am sendind any illegal data type through the `google.script.run`. The object coming from the client consists of three parameters which are all of string type. The return value from the server side script is a string. Like I said above in the description if I remove the withSuccessHandler hook the script works normaly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! You saved my day! I have been stuck with this error for a long time.